# Как можно проверить переменную на соответствие одной цифре из десятичной системы счисления?

Tags: php

Есть что-то короче этого

```
if ($var == 1 || $var == 2 || $var == 3 || $var == 4 || $var == 5 || $var == 6 || $var == 7 || $var == 8 || $var == 9 || $var == 0)
```

?

Comment: проверить integer и определить разрядность числа?

Comment: `if (in_array($var, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]))` а вообще смотря от задачи, что вы пытаетесь сделать и много ли чисел будет

Comment: `if($var>=0 && $var<=9)`

Comment: @Mike :D видимо мой мозг отказал мне в обслуживании, благодарю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('!^[0-9]$!',$var))
```

остальные предложенные варианты не годятся, в том числе и код автора вопроса

```
$var = "3 piglets";
var_dump($var == 1 || $var == 2 || $var == 3 || $var == 4 || $var == 5 || $var == 6 || $var == 7 || $var == 8 || $var == 9 || $var == 0);
var_dump(in_array($var, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]));
var_dump($var>=0 && $var<=9);
var_dump(preg_match('!^[0-9]$!',$var));

// bool(true)
// bool(true)
// bool(true)
// int(0)
```

Учим РНР, читаем про [приведение типов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Отличительной особенностью сайтов сети Stack Overflow является то, что большинство посетителей составляют люди, весьма поверхностно знакомые с предметом вопроса.

Comment: Репутация медианного участника равна, как известно, [единице](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296967/276994).

Comment: В общем случае, конечно, так. А для конкретной задачи автора (которую в деталях мы не знаем) `$var>=0 && $var<=9` может тоже вполне сгодиться.

Comment: "Конкретные задачи для автора" напрямую запрещены правилами. Сайты сети Stack Overflow предназначены для ответов именно на общие вопросы.

Comment: Да, это очень важно, как оказалось. Еще вариант: `var_dump((ctype_digit($var) && strlen($var) == 1));`

Comment: Хочу уточнить. Имеется пользовательская функция, которая берет данные из БД `SELECT COUNT()` она возвращает число типа `string`. Cтоит ли делать `return (int) $row;` если для меня не имеет значение тип возвращаемых данных (результат будет выведен на страницу как `echo 'Количество: ' . func();`)?
То есть произойдет двойное приведение к типу. Или это хороший тон, который приучает мозг не забывать о типах?

Comment: @Plush Нет, это не нужно. Проверка по ctype_digit вернет FALSE для 0.

Comment: Для `$var = '0'; // ctype_digit($var); возвращает bool(true)` — проверьте

Comment: @Plush я, кажется, писал 0, а не '0'

Comment: Ипатьев, а я думал мы говорим о строках которые содержат числа `$var = "3 piglets";`

Comment: @Plush мы говорим о функции, которая либо работает корректно, либо нет. Функция с type_digit($var) работает **некорректно**. Причин некорректной работы может быть много. У сtype_digit не та же самая причина, что и у $var == 1, но это не делает ее рабочей.

Answer (score 1):

Для тех, кто избегает регулярных выражений:
`if(sscanf($var,"%1d%s")==[$var,null])`,
так можно проверить и первую цифру, и отсутствие текста за ней.

Тест:

```
var_dump(sscanf($var="1","%1d%s")==[$var,null]);    
var_dump(sscanf($var="12","%1d%s")==[$var,null]);   
var_dump(sscanf($var="3 piglets", "%1d%s")==[$var,null]);
```

Результаты:

```
boolean true
boolean false
boolean false
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверить, что длина ровно один байт, а [ASCII-код](http://www.asciitable.com/) символа – от 48 до 57 (десятичные цифры):

```
if( strlen($var)==1  &&  ord($var)>=48  &&  ord($var)<=57)
```

Тесты:

```
0       true
1       true
2       true
3       true
4       true
5       true
6       true
7       true
8       true
9       true
10      false
11      false
'1'     true
'A'     false
'4Hero' false
'Ё'     false
'Стэк'  false
```